# 01 Knapsack specialization

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

Excuse me if this has been answered already, but I don't have a deep knowledge of algorithms and don't always notice the subtleties between different specializations of the algorithms.  I have (what I think is) a slight variant of the 01-Knapsack problem.  I have a knapsack that has max weight W, and there are N items to choose from that have a weight w and value v.  What I want to do is maximize the total value, V, without going over W.

Classic Knapsack.

**Here's the twist**: Of the items, I need to make sure that I have certain amounts (not up-to, but ***exact*** amounts) taken from different categories.

So lets assume that we have categories

- F - Food items
- T - Toys
- C - Clothes
- M - Miscellaneous (F, T, or C)

I'm going on a 2 day trip, so I need to take 2 Food items, 1 toy to amuse the kid, and 2 items of clothes.  And as a kicker, I can take one additional item that is either a F, T OR C.  Note that every item is unique and can be included only once.

From all of algos I've found, it seems like it's a hybrid of the 01 (unique items) and the bounded variant, though in the classic bounded knapsack we are binding the number of times we can include a particular item vs a particular **category**

If someone could point me to the right algorithm that'd be greatly appreciated. Bonus points for code in a "normal" language, and extra points if the implementation allows me to view the top n-number best results (you know, in case the optimal solution includes the toy that I just REALY can't stand or has 2 outfits that clash with each other).

EDIT: Note that I want to be able to go on longer trips eventually, so I'm looking at taking 8-10 items total and the categories can have up to 250 or so items (that kid has way too many toys).  I can do some optimizations to reduce *some* of the items in each category (I'm really not going to take the ugly hawaiian shirt), but I can't reduce it enough to make a straight brute force implementation feasible.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you have an overall knapsack problem with multiple sub-knapsack problems. Sounds like an optimization algorithm approach could probably start by eliminating impossible solutions first as your solution space is very small.

Comment: How is it that physical volume is not a consideration?

Comment: What is an ILP solver?

Comment: What's 'a "normal" language'?

Comment: @user1146334 ILP = [integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible ILP/LP formulation (the most obvious one, but there's never just one formulation), could be: (not tested)

```
maximize sum(v[i] * x[i])
subject to:
0 <= x[i] <= 1        // can take every item at most once
sum(w[i] * x[i]) <= W // don't go over the weight limit
F <= sum(f[i] * x[i]) <= F + 1 // take F or F+1 food items
T <= sum(t[i] * x[i]) <= T + 1 // take T or T+1 toys
C <= sum(c[i] * x[i]) <= C + 1 // take C or C+1 clothes
sum(x[i]) == F + T + C + M     // take exactly the right number of items
```

Where `v[i]` are values, `w[i]` are weights, `f[i]` are the "foodness" of items, `t[i]` are the "toyness" and by now you know what `c[i]` will be. Items that fall into more than one category count double or triple (ie if you take an edible toy, it will count towards the toys and towards the food items), which can be avoided by putting in multiple copies of that item, one for each of its categories, where the copies are in only one category each.

But now the real question, how can it be solved? That's still an area of active research, but here's an idea that should work well in this case.

With branch and bound. Bound using the linear relaxation (solve the above problem with linear programming, allowing the decision variables `x[i]` to be fractions), which should, for this problem, give a pretty decent bound (and admissible, it will always give a solution with an objective value that is at least as high as if you had solved an ILP problem). Branch on a variable that is not an integer.

Comment: It might be my misunderstanding, but the above doesn't seem to work.  For the F/T/C entries, I want to take an exact number of entries.  Seem like a simple fix to make it sum(f[i] * x[i]) == 2, etc.  But isn't that equation summing up the VALUE of the choices from F?  If f[i] = 123, that would throw off the equality.  Also, this seems like it is assuming that all items are in the x[i] vector.  That doesn't make sense since the groups are non-overlapping (except for M).

Comment: @user1146334 well the idea is that `f[i]` indicates whether item `i` is a food item (1) or not (0). `x[i]` indicates whether you take item `i` or not. So you multiply them together and sum them, you get the total number of food items that you're taking.

Comment: So I tried coding this up using puLP (pulp-or) but I'm not quite getting the right result.  I can finally get the result to be under W, but the problem I have is that I'm getting duplicates. When I come across items that cross boundries such as edible toys, I add a seperate copy.  For example, Let's say the first item is a RingPop.  So I add RingPop_f and then RingPop_t.  F is then F[1,0,...] and T[0,1,...].  When I get my results, I can get RingPop_t and RingPop_f, but I only want one of them.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also have problems with duplicates between the M (which includes an individual copy of everyone) and any of the other categories

Comment: @user1146334 If you want to take a RingPop only once, you can of course add a constraint to do that: `RingPop_f + RingPop_t <= 1`. To avoid duplicates with M, don't include M (just take more items, like I showed)

Comment: Ah I see. I still want to have one item from M, but I guess I could just do some post processing and say that if F,T,or C were the +1 then it now becomes the M.  How, though, do I prevent items from being duplicated between F, T, & C since every item is unique?  Would I have to add a constraint for every single item? (sorry for being such a pain, I've never even heard of an ILP/LP before this conversation)

Comment: @user1146334 yes, for every item that is in more than one category you'd need a constraint that ensures you can only take it once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44248/discussion-between-user1146334-and-harold)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to simply brute force all options.

Here is some example Python code:

```
from itertools import combinations
F=['apple','banana','clementine']
T=['compass','telephone']
C=['socks','gloves','hat']
weights={'apple':1,'banana':2,'clementine':3,'compass':4,'telephone':5,
       'socks':6,'gloves':7,'hat':8}
values={'apple':10,'banana':9,'clementine':8,'compass':7,'telephone':6,
       'socks':5,'gloves':4,'hat':3}
choices=[]
W=45  # Maximum allowed weight
n=5   # Number of choices to display
for M in range(3):  # M represents which category gets an extra item
    num_food = 3 if M==0 else 2
    num_toys = 2 if M==1 else 1
    num_clothes = 3 if M==2 else 2
    for food_to_take in combinations(F,num_food):
        for toys_to_take in combinations(T,num_toys):
            for clothes_to_take in combinations(C,num_clothes):
                things_to_take = food_to_take+toys_to_take+clothes_to_take
                weight = sum(weights[a] for a in things_to_take)
                value = sum(values[a] for a in things_to_take)
                if weight<=W:
                    choices.append([value,weight,things_to_take])
for value,weight,things_to_take in sorted(choices,reverse=True)[:n]:
    print value,weight,things_to_take
```

prints

```
43 23 ('apple', 'banana', 'clementine', 'compass', 'socks', 'gloves')
42 24 ('apple', 'banana', 'clementine', 'telephone', 'socks', 'gloves')
42 24 ('apple', 'banana', 'clementine', 'compass', 'socks', 'hat')
41 25 ('apple', 'banana', 'compass', 'telephone', 'socks', 'gloves')
41 25 ('apple', 'banana', 'clementine', 'telephone', 'socks', 'hat')
```

Comment: I don't think that brute forcing is an option.  Ultimately I want to go on longer trips, so I'm looking at taking 8 or 9 items and some of the categories have 200 or so items to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I think an approach based on Simulated Annealing could work well; SA has been widely applied to KPs, and it's simple to add extra constraints to the solution space. The basic strategy would be as follows:

1. Start with an initial admissible solution consisting of the requisite number of lowest-weight items in each category.
2. In each round, hypothesize replacing one item in a particular category with another item in that category.
3. If the hypothesized candidate solution is not admissible, go to 6.
4. Calculate an acceptance probability for the candidate solution based on its total value relative to the total value of the current solution, and on the annealing schedule.
5. Accept the candidate solution with the calculated probability. If it is accepted, it replaces the current solution; if it is not accepted, the current solution is unchanged.
6. If the total number of annealing rounds has been reached, exit. Otherwise, advance the annealing schedule and go to 2.

For problems that are not especially poorly conditioned, SA does quite well on knapsack problems, so I think it's likely to be fine for your use case. Introductory material on SA, and on annealing schedules and calculating acceptance probabilities, is widely available on the web.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, but sounds interesting. Looks like it's time to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

Use genetic algorithm to find an good solution in reasonable time by doing following:-

1. reserve slots in chromosomes for numbers required for each type. For example :-

   Food : milk,apple
    Toys : etc..
    ......
2. Start with valid solution like minimum weights of all types.
3. Try changing values of the items and check if its valid . Find crossover between them such like exchanging there types .
4. Evaluate the best chromosome with max value.
5. Do this till the best chromosome remains the same for fixed no of iterations.